# the meaning of the word 'but' in this sentence/

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence below and I can't exactly get the meaning of 'but.' I guess there is the word 'also' omitted. Am I correct?

> Kids are raised to say "Oh my Gosh" and not to "use God's name in vain" **but** saying "Oh my God".

Thank you !

Comment: A typo for **by**?

Comment: I think it's a error, and what was intended was _Kids are raised to say "Oh my Gosh" and not to "use God's name in vain" **by** saying "Oh my God"._ [ @KateBunting posted as I was typing ]

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding of the sentence is partially correct. However, there isn't necessarily an omitted word like "also" in this case.

I think the sentence should be like this:

> Kids are raised to say "Oh my Gosh" and not to use God's name in vain saying "Oh my God".

or

> Kids are raised not to use God's name in vain and say "Oh my Gosh" instead of saying "Oh my God".